# Animation to hide a cell in a table and re-size the remaining cells in the row.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, html-table

I've got a table with 100% width and three cells.

When I press a button, one cell is hidden, and the table layout adjusts accordingly.

I am currently using the .hide() jquery method to animate the hiding.

**HTML**

```
<table style="border-color:red;width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table><tr><td><div>stuff 1 blah blah blah</div></td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table><tr><td><div>stuff 2 blah blah blah</div></td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td id="tdStuff"> 
             <table><tr><td><div>stuff 3 blah blah blah</div></td></tr></table>           
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnHide" onclick="hideStuff()" >Hide</button>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
function hideStuff(){
    $('#tdStuff').hide('slow');
}
```

But the problem is that even though it adjusts smoothly at first,  the text in the cell gets squashed up. And, if there is a fixed width anywhere, it stops adjusting and simply jumps.

Is there a way I can get the animation to happen smoothly by expanding the remaining cells in the row to fit the width of the table.

Relevant [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrMYL/12)

Comment: A simple google search on "hide() animation jquery" will give you the result MitchS gave.

Just saying, to help you in the future. 

And no I did not downvote your question.

Comment: I don't see the given answer as satisfactory. Sure, it adjusts smoothly at first, but then the text in the cell gets squashed up. And, if there is a fixed width anywhere, it stops adjusting and simply jumps. http://jsfiddle.net/hrMYL/12/

Comment: I have restructured the question. See if you can get the mods to reopen it.

Comment: @Abijeet Patro Thank you. I've approved the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jQuery has functionality for this, try the following adjustment:

`$('#tdStuff3').hide('slow');`

See the documentation on [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for more information.